# ASP.NET Entity Framework load nested related data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to load nested related data in ASP.NET Web Api 2 Entity framework.
My code looks like this:

Client.cs:

```
public class Client
    {
        [Key]
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Vat> Vats { get; set; }
    }
```

Vat.cs

```
public class Vat
    {
        [Key]
        public int VatId { get; set; }
        public MonthEnum Month { get; set; }

        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("ClientId")]
        public Client Client { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    }
```

Expense.cs

```
public class Expense
    {
        [Key]
        public int ExpenseId { get; set; }
        public string ExpenseTitle { get; set; }
        public ExpenseCategory Category { get; set; }
        public double[] Amounts { get; set; }
        public double Total { get; set; }
        public double VatAmount { get; set; }
        public double AfterVat { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public int VatId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("VatId")]
        public Vat Vat { get; set; }
    }
```

ClientContext.cs

```
public class ClientContext : DbContext
    {
        public ClientContext() : base("name=ClientContext")
        {
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<AccountantBackend.Models.Client> Clients { get; set; }
    }
```

ClientController.cs

```
private ClientContext db = new ClientContext();

// GET: api/Clients
public IQueryable<Client> GetClients()
{
     return db.Clients.Include(client => client.Vats);
}
```

I'm able to load the client with the related vats but the related expenses are always null.

Returned JSON:

```
{
    "ClientId": 1,
    "Name": "Tal",
    "Age": 19,
    "CompanyName": "Tal",
    "Address": "Hazon Ish 131",
    "LastUpdate": "2020-09-25T20:23:24.193",
    "Vats": {
        "VatId": 1
        "Month": 1
        "Expenses": null
    }
}
```

I tried to include also the expenses in the controller but nothing worked.
I'm not able to use ThenInclude even when I use a lambda expression in the include:

```
return db.Clients.Include(client => client.Vats).ThenInclude(vat => vat.Expenses);
```

**IQueryable does not contain a defintion for 'ThenInclude' and no accessible method 'ThenInclude' accepting a first argument of type IQueryable could be found**

I tried also the SelectMany function and it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong and how can I load nested relation data?

Comment: What are you using Entity Framework or Entity Framework Core? `ThenInclude` is an ef core feature, in ef 6 you do `query.Include(x => x.Collection.Select(y => y.Property))`.

Comment: According to the base constructor call here `public ClientContext() : base("name=ClientContext")` this has to be EF6, since EF Core `DbContext` has no constructor taking `string` argument.

Comment: @IvanStoev You're right, also `Include` and `ThenInclude` are in the same namespace. There is no reason for the error message if he was using ef core